# What does blue coloured rectangular around my name mean?

Tags: support, comments, user-interface, display-names

Can someone explain, why my name got rectangular like this, [as shown at picture]

> [image]

When a day before I just like the other which does not have.

Comment: [A blue background on the user information box in the lower-right corner of the answer indicates an answer posted by the asker of the question. The same holds true for comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22185/)

Comment: yes. thanks anyway for giving [`a good link`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That blue rectangular around your name in comments indicates that you are the OP (Original Poster - Questioner)

Comment: oh my God.. thanks anyway.. I just realized it.